# El navegador no muestra los cambios de las variables en los ficheros ".ts" - Angular

Tags: angular

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto en *Angular*, y nada más empezar me he topado con un problema inesperado. Antes de nada, dejo en claro que tanto el proyecto como el componente que estoy usando están recién creados, solo he cambiado lo imprescindible.

**app-component.html**:

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<app-cabecera></app-cabecera>
```

**app-component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
}
```

**cabecera.component.html**

```
<p>
  Esto es el texto de la cabecera: {{texto}}
</p>
```

**cabecera.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-cabecera',
    templateUrl: './cabecera.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./cabecera.component.css']
})

export class CabeceraComponent implements OnInit {
    texto:string;
    constructor() { 
        this.texto='ejemplo';
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

Mi problema es que los cambios que hago en las variables de mis archivos **.ts** no se actualizan automaticamente (ni recargando la página). Si pongo texto plano en los **HTML** se actualizan sin problemas, pero las modificaciones en las variables llamadas con `{{texto}}` o `{{title}}` no se reflejan (a menos que finalice manualmente `ng serve` y vuelva a ejecutarlo).

Llevo dándole muchas vueltas y no entiendo ni sé por qué no puede funcionar, como he dicho, son archivos nuevos.

Comment: Este problema parece relacionado con `angular-cli` más que con Angular.js 2 (éste no tiene ningún comando `ng` de `cli`). ¿Qué versión usas? Hay un ticket que habla sobre un límite que hay que aumentar para que funcione correctamente o incluso con un `sync` basta a veces: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1610

Comment: Cualquier cambio en el código debería provocar una recompilación, que queda reflejada en la línea de comandos. ¿Se está enterando ng de tus cambios?

Answer (score 1):

quizás tengas espacios o caracteres especiales en la carpeta de tu proyecto o en el directorio superior, es un problema reportado con Angular-cli: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2287

Un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad @KarlosCode. Recuerda que si tienes una opinión respecto a la pregunta pero no tienes certeza de ello deberías ponerlo como comentario de la pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por la info y la bienvenida, no puedo hacer comentarios hasta que tenga 50 puntos y me pareció que la respuesta podría aportar algo a la comunidad.

Comment: No sé si lo habrás consultado, pero aquí tienes un enlace de interés: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer no sé cuántos puntos da votar positivo tu comentario, pero allá van los que sean para que te quede menos para poder enviar comentarios.